# error 3734 - database has been placed in state by the user that prevents it from being locked

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao

I am trying to connect a DAO database to an already open database. It keeps on bringing up error 3734.

Ive checked that the database properties are open in shared mode and default record locking is No Locks.

code is
{
{.DataBaseName = .ProjectPath & "\TheMasterPlan.accdb"

```
    Set .db = OpenDatabase(.DataBaseName, False, False) }
```

Alternatively can I set a DAO recorset to this database without opening the database.

Comment: Yes to last sentence. You can define any DAO database in memory without opening it. Please flesh out your context with more than 1 line snippet and maybe we can help.

Comment: I want read/write access a table in an access application that is already open. Id prefer to use DAO as many of the other sub routines that I have are based on DAO. At the moment, using the OpenDatabase method creates an error.

Comment: Hi Im going to start this question again as I didn't word it particularly well. the issue is around trying to multithread loop routines to improve speed but it is causing issues when I try to open a common database file.